# "headers already sent" error occurs ONLY when page opened with header() function

Tags: php, http-headers

So I've been tracking down this "headers already sent" error for a week now.

I have checked

- that none of my files have white space at the top or bottom
- that I don't have a UTF_8 BOM issue
- that there are no prints or echos or other outputs before the call to header()

The error happens when I try to go to the Home page directly from the Login page:

- Enter username and password
- Click the "Login" button
- This code executes:

  ```
  $redirect_to = "Location:" . BASE_URL . "src/home.php";
  exit(header($redirect_to));
  ```

And I get this error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/brekra50/groupxsolutions.com/inc/header_start.html:10) in /home/brekra50/groupxsolutions.com/index.php on line 103

BUT....

If I go back to the Login page and click on the "Contact Us" button in the footer, the Contact page opens just fine.  AND if I then click on the "Home" button on the Contact page, the Home page (which just threw the warning) now opens NO PROBLEM!

In that case I am opening the Home page from a button click with this code;

```
<li ><a href=<?php echo BASE_URL ."src/home.php"; ?> class=<?php echo set_nav_classes(HOME_PAGE, $curr_page); ?> >Home</a></li>
```

This is obviously some clue as to my problem, but I can't figure it out.  Is the header() function itself sending the headers, so that when the Home page opens from that function the warning gets triggered?  If so, how do I get around that?

Here is the code from line 10 of header_start.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href= <?php echo BASE_URL . "css/fix.css"; ?> type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Here is the code from the index.php file, lines 102 and 103:

```
$redirect_to = "Location:" . BASE_URL . "src/home.php";
exit(header($redirect_to));
```

"JustOn..."  I think has pointed me in the right direction.  I have two "require_once()" calls at the very top of the index.php page, which must happen before the call to header().  I think that is the output issue.

Now... what to do about it.

Comment: `output started at /home/brekra50/groupxsolutions.com/inc/header_start.html:10` well there's your problem.

Comment: Can you post the relevant lines of this file `/home/brekra50/groupxsolutions.com/index.php on line 103`? Preferably line 103...

Comment: You're missing the point, the home page is not throwing that error, the login page is when the form is processed.

Comment: You have to know the connection between the use of `header()` and the way php is creating headers and oputput: http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php  & http://php.net/manual/de/function.headers-sent.php & http://php.net/manual/de/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: Could you post the code sections where you redirect from the login to the home page, as well as the beginning of the home page?

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand that "include()" and "require()" functions are also outputs and are causing my error, I couldn't just get rid of them, as they are key to the entire design of the site.

So in the php documentation I found a code snippet that lets me open my pages with javascript, which avoids the entire "headers starting" issue.

```html
if (!headers_sent()) {
 $redirect_to = "Location:" . BASE_URL . "src/home.php";
 exit(header($redirect_to));
} else {
 $filename = BASE_URL . "src/home.php";
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
 echo 'window.location.href="' . $filename . '";';
 echo '</script>';

 echo '<noscript>';
 echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=' . $filename . '" />';
 echo '<noscript>';

 exit;
}
```